# How to get millions of lines from Azure Table Storage when you know the Pkey and RowKey

Tags: azure-table-storage

I have a Table in Azure in which I keep users and their information. However I want to extract from whole table a subset of about 400k, for which I know the Pkey and RowKey -> an user id.

Is there an operator like $in (mongo) or IN (sql). How do I transmit all these rowkeys to extract the value from that line? It's a huge array.

One way is to get it one by one, but it will take a lot of time and will cost very much.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this with Azure Tables. The best to handle this type of operation is to build a secondary table that contains the information you need. The secondary information is built at the same time as the primary table, by sending a BATCH operation that updates both tables at the same time consistently. This technique essentially helps you build Index tables. See this article for an example on [how to use the BATCH operation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-table-storage-20/#insert-batch).

Comment: I fail to see how a secondary table would help in this scenario. I assume the subset is arbitrary (dynamic)

Comment: Ah... there is no selection logic you can apply? Define arbitrary. Random? Can better explain what you are trying to solve then?

Comment: Herve's first sentence is correct. "You can't really do this with Azure Tables". His suggestion of secondary table would apply to a scenario where you grouped some set of records and gave them all the same partitionkey, you could then later select that set by reading all records by partitionkey, which azure storage supports. There is no IN() syntax as you would like.